# LessCSS: Don't add newlines for comments

Tags: css, less

Is there any Less preprocessor on Mac that preserves "inline" comments (without minifying)?  I have a script for creating different CSS themes from the same file, and it relies on inline comments to switch out rules:

```
.what {
    width: 200px; /* what-width */
}
```

All the Less preprocessors I've used turn this into:

```
.what {
    width: 200px; 
    /* what-width */
}
```

...which is less preferable.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The best I know of at present is to put the comment *before* the semicolon, but that would probably require a change in your script (and still does not look as nice):

**LESS and CSS Output are**

```
.what {
    width: 200px /* what-width */;
}
```